# How to stop IE from changing transparent backgrounds when animating opacity?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, animation, opacity

I cannot seem to animate opacity with images in IE using jQuery, it gives them slight outlined backgrounds.  I've seen many threads on this, but none really like mine.  How can I stop IE from adding this outline? See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5mA6/1/)

I have also uploaded an image that displays the rough borders.  You can't see it that well with that image, but it is a noticeable difference between when you mouse over and mouse out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the artifacts that are created around your question marks, that's because IE is really bad with png alpha.

If you can afford it, try using a non-transparent image (white background).

Comment: If this is it then my answer is wrong. But I really can't see any difference in IE7/8/9 and chrome in the jsfiddle. Maybe my eyes are bad? :P